# using chain.js for complex templates and images?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, templating

I'm researching the possible use of the jquery plugin chain.js over other templating systems such as jTemplate.

the site is a large online retailer. We have a category page showing a large list of products, dresses for example. A user can click on a link on a nav bar te refine the results based on attributes such as colour, size etc.

We have an ajax call contacting the server and we use a template plugin to rebuild the page.

Anyway - our product template needs to have an image and various price fields underneath it. On jTemplate we have conditionals to alter the template slightly. We dont seem to be able to do this with chain.js.

Also I can't seem to bind to tag attributes using chain - for example binding a product image url to the image src tag.

is this impossible?

Any pointers would be great - finding a severe lack of online resources for using chain.js.

thanks,

bc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just closing this off - eventually we scrapped Chain as we found it wasteful compared to Trimpath JavaScript Templates (TrimpathJST). We used this method in the end.

Comment: Can you describe how you found it wasteful? In some ways it seems pretty appealing from a code succinctness perspective and also being able to write it using real HTML.